# Sorting a list of words according its position in a given string in dart

Tags: string, flutter, dart, sorting

I want to sort list of words depending on its position in a given string.

```html
/// "Karim is an engineer"
/// ["engine","karim is","an"]
/// After sorting it will be:
/// ["Karim is","an",engine"]
```

Comment: can  you be specific with language, seems to random word, Also can you describe a little more about the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not really sorting... what i do ? i create an empty array. if a word in the given string is found in my list of words to be sorted, then i add that word to the empty array. However, the result is what expected.

```
  List<String> yourList = ["engineer", "Karim", "an", "is"];
  List<String> result = [];
  String givenString = "Karim is an engineer";
  List<String> wordsInStr = givenString.split(' ');
  
  for (String wrd in wordsInStr) {
    if (yourList.contains(wrd)) {
      result.add(wrd);
    }
  }
  
  print(result);
}
```